# Angular Instagram endpoint embed issue

Tags: angularjs, embed, instagram, feed, endpoint

I have a sample Angular app that fetches all content from a user through an endpoint, without the use of calling hashtags. I can get the retrieve photos with a given hashtag example to work, but I would rather just get the entire feed of a user.This is the working content link for the sample:

var endPoint = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=642176ece1e7445e99244cec26f4de1f&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";

I registered my new app, have the client ID and client secret, and I'm just trying to embed the entire user feed into a page.

While looking through https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/ I can't seem to find a link that works with a client ID and Client Secret.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show the code where you are trying to do this.

Comment: Here is a link to the entire js file: http://rejectionsketch.com/index.js

Answer (score 0):

There is never going to be a "link" that works with your client secret.  The client secret is to be used with a back-end programming language using the instagram SDK.  If you passed your client secret through a simple URL or front-end programming language, it wouldn't be secret anymore ;).

**Some example SDK's / libraries**:

- Node: https://github.com/totemstech/instagram-node
- Python: https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram
- Ruby: https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem

If you don't want to use a back-end language, you'll need to get a `token` and use that in your links.  **More info on tokens here**: https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the links! I have checked out the token link, and I do realize the secret shouldn't be in the link. When I registered, I got those two values, and specified two redirect URLs. I don't want a user to authenticate with instagram, I just want to be able to embed the entire feed of a user without using any tags.    This works:      var endPoint = [link]https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/MYTAG/media/recent?client_id=MYCLIENTID&callback=JSON_CALLBACK[link]    Is there a way to eliminate tags/MYTAG and have users/MYUSER to just get a feed?

Comment: You can get a user's media: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/?hl=en#get_users_media_recent